# Can I remove studs under a header to fit a refrigerator?

Tags: framing

The picture below shows a 10' kitchen wall on the first floor, of an existing house. The yellow rectangle represents a cabinet location.  Would it be safe to remove the two 2x4s indicated by the green arrows, from below the cabinet to the floor.  I am trying to gain a couple of additional inches to fit in a standard size refrigerator (below the cabinet).  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Someone didn’t think through where a fridge should go. Sigh. Will the few inches actually do the trick? And where are the coils and how much clearance does the manual say is needed?

Comment: You appear to be in the rough-in stage. Why don't you ask your contractor? If you're doing this DIY, I'd be concerned about where you're going to run the wiring that passes through those studs. Appears to be at least 2 receptacle boxen there.

Comment: @FreeMan -- it's not in the rough-in stage. It's a 15 year old house.  The receptacle on this side of the wall will move above the fridge (I have a 6" hidden gap between the fridge and cabinet).  I will have to lose the outlet on the other side of the wall.

Comment: @Jon Custer -- thanks -- very good point about coil location and clearance.

Comment: Are you planning to put sheetrock on the back side?  I would guess that's why the studs are there - something to nail to.  You'll also need to take out the bottom plate if you want to slide the refrigerator further back, won't you?

Comment: @Mark - Yes, there is already dry-wall on the other side of the wall in the picture. When the studs come out, the plan is to put plywood as backing for the dry-wall.  And yes, the bottom plate will have to be removed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those studs are not likely to be load-bearing. There's a robust stack of studs acting as a post which appear to support the primary beam terminating at that location. Interior studs that near the post would not also carry load. You can verify this by looking below the subfloor to assess the load path.

Your construction drawings will also indicate the details of that beam and its support structure. I suggest looking at that, or just ask your builder.

Comment: thank you! The primary beam runs 14' to the right, to the end of the house.  I'm curious what that line on the beam is, in the visible section of the beam.  It can't be two pieces, can it? [To clarify, this is a pre-existing house, so I can't visually inspect it].

Comment: That's a laminated beam. You're seeing the joint between sections of the outer ply. That's normal and expected.